# Simplify $|1 - \frac{5}{6}e^{-i2\pi f}+\frac{1}{6}e^{-i2\pi f2}|^2$ to real valued form easily

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, trigonometry

How can I simplify 
$$|1 - \frac{5}{6}e^{-i2\pi f}+\frac{1}{6}e^{-i2\pi f2}|^2$$
to real-valued form easily?

Comment: What does the "$2$" mean in "$f2$" which appears in the second exponential? Is it supposed to be "$f^2$"?

Comment: no, simply a constant. Can be written $-i4\pi f$ @MPW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\ca{\cos(\alpha)}
\def\caa{\cos(2\alpha)}
\def\sa{\sin(\alpha)}
\def\saa{\sin(2\alpha)}
\def\fa{\tfrac{5}{6}}
\def\fb{\tfrac{1}{6}}$

Let $\alpha=2\pi f$ which gives
\begin{align*}
z
&=1-\fa e^{i\,(-2\pi f)}+\tfrac{1}{6}e^{i\,(-4\pi f)}
\\&=1-\fa e^{i\,(-\alpha)}+\fb e^{i\,(-2\alpha)}
\\&=1-\fa\bigl(\ca-i\sa\bigr)+\fb\bigl(\caa-i\saa\bigr)
\\&=1-\fa\ca+i\fa\sa+\fb\caa-i\fb\saa
\\&=1-\fa\ca+\fb\caa+i\bigl(\fa\sa-\fb\saa\bigr).
\end{align*}

We have
\begin{align*}
\lvert z \rvert^2
&=z\cdot\overline{z}
\\&=\Bigl(1-\fa\ca+\fb\caa+i\bigl(\fa\sa-\fb\saa\bigr)\Bigr)
\\&\qquad\cdot\Bigl(1-\fa\ca+\fb\caa-i\bigl(\fa\sa-\fb\saa\bigr)\Bigr)
\\&=\bigl(1-\fa\ca+\fb\caa\bigr)^2+\bigl(\fa\sa-\fb\saa\bigr)^2
\\&=\tfrac{1}{36}\bigl(6-5\ca+\caa\bigr)^2+\tfrac{1}{36}\bigl(5\sa-\saa\bigr)^2
\end{align*}
which is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
36\lvert z \rvert^2
&=\bigl(6-5\ca+\caa\bigr)^2+\bigl(5\sa-\saa\bigr)^2
\\&=\bigl(6-5\ca\bigr)^2+2\bigl(6-5\ca\bigr)\caa+\caa^2
\\&\qquad{}+25\sa^2-10\sa\saa+\saa^2
\\&=36-60\ca+25\ca^2
\\&\qquad{}+12\caa-10\ca\caa+\caa^2
\\&\qquad{}+25\sa^2-10\sa\saa+\saa^2
%
\\&=36-60\ca+25(\ca^2+25\sa^2)
\\&\qquad{}+(\caa^2+\saa^2)+12\caa
\\&\qquad{}-10\ca\caa-10\sa\saa
%
\\&=36-60\ca+25+1+12\caa
\\&\qquad{}-10\ca\caa-10\sa\saa
%
\\&=62-60\ca+12\caa
\\&\qquad{}-10\ca\caa-10\sa\saa
%
\\&=62-60\ca+12\caa
\\&\qquad{}-10\bigl(\ca\caa+\sa\saa\bigr)
%
\\&=62-60\ca+12\caa-10\ca
%
\\&=62-70\ca+12\caa
\end{align*}
since
$$
\ca
=\cos(2\alpha-\alpha)
=\cos(2\alpha)\cos(\alpha)+\sin(2\alpha)\sin(\alpha).
$$

Thus
$$
36\lvert z \rvert^2=62-70\ca+12\caa
$$
i.e.
\begin{align*}
\lvert z \rvert^2
&=\tfrac{1}{36}\bigl(62-70\ca+12\caa\bigr)
\\&=\tfrac{1}{18}\bigl(31-35\ca+6\caa\bigr)
\\&=\tfrac{1}{18}\bigl(31-35\cos(2\pi f)+6\cos(4\pi f)\bigr).
\end{align*}